# What type of string is this?

Tags: string

What kind of string is this at the end of this lanyard? I want to find string like this. It's to attach to a loop.

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you post a clearer picture? I assume it's very finely woven thread, but it looks almost like leather.

Answer (score 5):

If it's the same as I've got on my phone lanyard - which it looks like it is - it's braided nylon cord.

You might want 1mm to 2mm.  Both are widely available, but the little loops like that are often 1mm or 1.5mm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the USA or Canada you might be familiar with Handy Hundred string, which is common in 2.5 mm / about 1/10" or there abouts.
The same kind of line is also for sale as braided fishing line in 0.9mm (1/32"?)
While not the same string it is near enough to do the work and seems readily available online in/from the USA.

In Europe you sometimes find string that will do the same job in shipchandlers as braided whipping line, and something that might do the job in builders markets as string to use in brick laying, but I have never been able to find a reliable source from one time to the next.
I guess these options might also work in the rest of the world but I have not tested that for myself.

Comment: Possibly 1/32" as (with a few exceptions) inch fractions are multiples of powers of 2. That should also take knots well, unlike some cords +1

Comment: I use that 0.9 mm cord (and it is marked as such in the USA) for many different knot jobs and decorative knotwork, it does take knots well. It is the anchor to the netting I do right now with just a reef knot to tie it into a loop. Might hold knots better than the sample in the OP photo.

Comment: If it's even marked as 0.9mm in the US, I guess it really is 0.9mm and not something in inches.  Some of the phone lanyard string I've come across knots securely but commercially it may be secured with clips and overhand knots as stop knots, or (in the case of the one I have here) fused into a loop with the join hidden in a plastic widget.  Some doesn't knot as well, though I've never found any that won't take a double or triple fisherman's bend securely - if I did I'd throw it away!